# How to download a specific directory w/o the creation of the directory path from the root of the site to the specified directory

Tags: wget

```
wget -r -np www.a.com/b/c/d
```

The above will create a directory called 'www.a.com' in the current working directory on my local computer, containing all subdirectories on the path to 'd'.

I **only** want directory 'd' (and its contents) created in my cwd.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I found the options to do just that, and they are: -nH --cut-dirs=<num>

Comment: The thing is, there's a right way to ask a question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist This will raise the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I actually did provide what I've tried in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention that directory name explicitely and avoid creation of sub-directories by the following line.

```
wget -nd -P /home/d www.a.com/b/c/d
```

The -nd will avoid creation of sub-directories and -P will set the directory to /home/d and all your files will be downloaded to "/home/d" folder only.